# Grouping application settings

Tags: .net, vb.net

My VB.net application has a lot of application settings, is it possible to group them somehow (other than having a common name)?

For example, my application has a lot of winforms each of which needs to save some information about itself. Is it possible to use something like:

```
   Form1.width = My.Settings.Form1.Width
   Form2.width = My.Settings.Form2.Width
```

etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a naming convention that will do that (instead of . notation):

```
Form1.width = My.Settings.Form1Width
Form2.width = My.Settings.Form2Width
```

Comment: Yes I had thought of that but I thought there was a more 'object' way of doing it

Comment: @ajordison - Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Fair enough, it just looks like one of those things that should be possible. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Nice, I was looking for this, but I suggest bind the property of the form to the application settings instead of assigning them manually.